# Creating multiple distance matrices; DISTATIS DistanceFromSort() error

Tags: r, sorting, statistics, package

For the analysis of sensory sorting data I want to perform the statistical method DISTATIS. 26 judges sorted 6 water bottles into groups. This is what my data looks like:

```
                S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 S19 S20 S21 S22 S23 S24 S25 S26
AcquaPanna       2  1  3  3  6  3  5  2  1   6   2   2  11   1   5   3   1   5   1   1   5   3   3   3   1   4
CrystalGeyser    1  4  4  6  3  2  2  2  3   4   3   4   5   2   2   2   2   4   3   7   9   3   4   1   1  10
DavisTapA        2  4  3  6  2  2  6  2  1   2   3   5   8   1   1   2   1   3   3   7   2   2   6   3   4   5
DavisTapB        5  4  4  1  4  3  3  2  4   1   4   1  10   4   4   3   2   8   1   6   6   2   2   2   2   9
EternalAlkaline  5  1  1  2  6  2  1  1  1   1   2   5   3   1   3   3   2   6   2   4   8   3   3   3   5   7
Evian            4  4  4  2  3  2  3  2  2   6   4   1  10   3   5   3   5   8   1   6   7   1   4   2   2   9
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
#Loading the data    
water.data = read.csv("C:/Users/water.csv",TRUE,",",row.names="Water")
#Loading distatis package
library(DistatisR)
#Create distance matrices for each panelist using DistatisR package
distw = DistanceFromSort(water.data)
#Running the Distatis
distatis(distw)
```

I get this error when executing `DistanceFromSort()`:

```
package ‘DistanceFromSort’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
```

What can I do now to still be able to execute DISTATIS; how can I get a set of 26 individual distance matrices?

Comment: Your code run in my env. I use R version 3.4.2 and DistatisR version 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for your response cuttlefish44. For me it worked now aswell